# Trouble Readiing Google.Apis.Gmail.V1 email from .Net using ServiceAccount impersonation

Tags: c#, .net, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have code that works well when I authorize with a `Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential`. The same code does not work when I switch to a `Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential`.

The trouble could be in one of three places:

1. 1). Am I constructing the `ServiceAccountCredential` correctly?

   2). Am I using the `ServiceAccountCredential` correctly to access the
   user's account?

   3). Did the GA Admin give the service account proper access to read
   user's mail?

This is the code that is not working:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Discovery.v1;
using Google.Apis.Discovery.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
string[] asScopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailModify };
        string msApplicationName = "Gmail API .NET Quickstart";
    string sClientEmail = "blah@blah.gserviceaccount.com" //service account;
        string sUser = "cfo@mydomain.com" //email of the user that I want to read;
        string sPrivateKey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----  blah"//service account private key;
    string[] asScopes = {"https://mail.google.com/"};

    //get credential
    ServiceAccountCredential oCred = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(sClientEmail)
    {
        Scopes = asScopes,
        User = sUser //the user to be impersonated
    }.FromPrivateKey(sPrivateKey));

    // Create Gmail API service.
        GmailService oSVC  = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = oCred,
            ApplicationName = msApplicationName,
         });

        // List labels.
        UsersResource.LabelsResource.ListRequest request = oSVC.Users.Labels.List("me");
    IList<Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Label> labels = request.Execute().Labels;    //<--error here.
     /* --- fails with:
    Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException was unhandled HResult=-2146233088 Message=Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method.", Uri:"" Source=Google.Apis.Auth
    */
```

If anyone could help with examples of how to test a `ServiceAccountCredential` to see if it is constructed correctly, and further, what it has been authorized to, I'd really appreciate it.

These are the credentials set for my ClientID
[image]

A nagging question in all this is if I can even create a `ServiceAccountCredential` from a PrivateKey, as all the examples I have seen use a Certificate, eg:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2("key2.p12", "notasecret",
                X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            string userEmail = "abc@gmail.com";

            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                {
                    Scopes = new string[] { Gmail.v1.GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly }
                }.FromCertificate(certificate)
            );
```

Comment: First off, did you check the Implementing [Server-Side Authorization](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server) guide about service accounts?

Comment: @nogui - Your link is to UserAuth, not SerbiceAuth, your link is not relevant to what I am working on.. If you are asking if I read the documentation: YES I read all the google documentation, and really spent a long time looking at the github comments where the .net code is hosted, before posting on SO.

Answer (score 0):

YAHOO! I GOT IT WORKING!!

So the key was:
**1). DWD must be checked when creating service account.**
2). To have the application authorized for EXACTLY the scopes I needed to use.  **So your Google Admin has got to give your app exactly the scopes you need.**

Here is the code:

```
private const string MC_GOOGLE_APP_NAME = "from-google-00110";
private const string MC_GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT = "appname@from-google-00110.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
private const string MC_PRIVATE_KEY = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\xxxx blah blah blah xxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
private const string MS_GMAIL_QUERY = "label: inbox, label: unread";

//**** CRITICAL! THIS MUST EXACTLY MATCH THE SCOPES THAT YOUR App IS AUTHORZIED FOR ***
private const string MS_SCOPES ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify"; 
private string msEmailAccount = "mike@blue-mosaic.com"; //the email account you are reading, not mine please

//get credential for service account
ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(MC_GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT)
                {
                    Scopes = MS_SCOPES,
                    User = msEmailAccount 
                }.FromPrivateKey(MC_PRIVATE_KEY));

//create a new gmail service
GmailService oSVC =  GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = MC_GOOGLE_APP_NAME,
            });

List<Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message> aoMessageList = new List<Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message>();
UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest request = oSVC.Users.Messages.List(msEmailAccount);
request.Q = MS_GMAIL_QUERY;

//keep making requests until all messages are read. 
do
{
    ListMessagesResponse response = request.Execute();
    if (response.Messages != null)
    {
        aoMessageList.AddRange(response.Messages);
        request.PageToken = response.NextPageToken;
    }

} while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.PageToken));

//now read the body of each of the new messages
foreach (Message oMsg in aoMessageList)
{
    string sMsgID = oMsg.Id;

    sState = "Reading Message '" + sMsgID + "'";

    // and this one gets a bit nuts. processing GMAIL messages took me a fair amount
    // of reading, parsing and decoding, so it required a whole class!!
    SaneMessage oThisMsg = new SaneMessage(oSVC, "me", sMsgID);

    //and do something with the message
}
```

So the code above not only shows getting logged in, it also shows reading email.  For reading Google Apps email, it required a bunch of parsing to deal with URL encoded Base64 encoded messages that often had weird breaks in them.  I wrote a class to handle all this:

```
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Email_Reader_Service
{
    class SaneMessage
    {

        private string msID = "";
        private string msFrom = "";
        private string msDate = "";
        private string msSubject = "";
        private string msBody = "";

        public string ID
        {
            get { return msID; }
        }

        public string From
        {
            get { return msFrom; }
        }

        public DateTime Date
        {
            get { return Convert.ToDateTime(msDate); }
        }

        public string Subject
        {
            get { return msSubject; }
        }

        public string Body
        {
            get { return msBody; }
        }

        public SaneMessage(GmailService service, String userId, String messageId)
        {
            Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message oStupidMessage = service.Users.Messages.Get(userId, messageId).Execute();

            string sBackupDate = string.Empty;
            foreach (var mParts in oStupidMessage.Payload.Headers)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("{0}\t\t\t\t{1}", mParts.Name, mParts.Value);
                switch (mParts.Name)
                {
                    case ("X-Google-Original-Date"):
                        msDate = mParts.Value;
                        break;
                    case ("Date"):
                        sBackupDate = mParts.Value;
                        break;
                    case ("From"):
                        msFrom = mParts.Value;
                        break;
                    case ("Subject"):
                        msSubject = mParts.Value;
                        break;
                }
            }

            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            //the fooking date comes in a plethora of formats.  if the timezone name is appended on the end
            // the datetime conversion can't convert.
            if(msDate.Length == 0)
                msDate = sBackupDate;

            if (msDate.Contains('('))
                msDate= msDate.Substring(0, msDate.LastIndexOf('('));
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            if (msDate != "" && msFrom != "")
            {
                string sEncodedBody;
                if (oStupidMessage.Payload.Parts == null && oStupidMessage.Payload.Body != null)
                {
                    sEncodedBody = oStupidMessage.Payload.Body.Data;
                }
                else
                {
                    sEncodedBody = getNestedParts(oStupidMessage.Payload.Parts, "");
                }


                ///need to replace some characters as the data for the email's body is base64
                msBody = DecodeURLEncodedBase64EncodedString(sEncodedBody);

            }

        }

        private string getNestedParts(IList<MessagePart> part, string curr)
        {
            string str = curr;
            if (part == null)
            {
                return str;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var parts in part)
                {
                    if (parts.Parts == null)
                    {
                        if (parts.Body != null && parts.Body.Data != null)
                        {
                            str += parts.Body.Data;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return getNestedParts(parts.Parts, str);
                    }
                }

                return str;
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Turn a URL encoded base64 encoded string into readable UTF-8 string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sInput">base64 URL ENCODED string.</param>
        /// <returns>UTF-8 formatted string</returns>
        private string DecodeURLEncodedBase64EncodedString(string sInput)
        {
            string[] asInput = sInput.Split("=".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            string sOutput = string.Empty;

            foreach (string sInputPiece in asInput)
            {
                string sBase46codedBody = sInputPiece.Replace("-", "+").Replace("_", "/");  //get rid of URL encoding, and pull any current padding off.
                string sPaddedBase46codedBody = sBase46codedBody.PadRight(sBase46codedBody.Length + (4 - sBase46codedBody.Length % 4) % 4, '=');  //re-pad the string so it is correct length.

                byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(sPaddedBase46codedBody);
                sOutput += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
            }

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("{0}\r\n\r\n", sOutput);

            return sOutput;
        }
    }
}
```